# How to add yticks to one specific point

Tags: python, matplotlib, yticks

I have bunch of numbers (lets say all less than 500) and some 'inf' in my data. I want to plot them using integer numbers (I represent 'inf' with 1000). However, on y axis of plot, I want to write 'inf' instead of 1000. If I use 'plt.yticks', I can add label to all y points which is not what I want. How can I add a label to one specific point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the both the data position of the ticks and the labels of the ticks.  Here is an example of a scatter plot with 3 extra points at "infinity".  It does not look great because the extra points are at 1000, and there are ticks showing in the white space.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# create some data, plot it.
x = np.random.random(size=300)
y = np.random.randint(0,500, 300)
x_inf = [0,.1,.2]
y_inf = [1000,1000,1000]

plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.scatter(x_inf, y_inf)
```

[image]

First grab the axis.  Then we can overwrite what data positions should have ticks, in this case 0 to 500 in steps of 100, and then 1000.  Then we can also overwrite the labels of the ticks themselves.

```
ax = plt.gca()
# set the positions where we want ticks to appear
ax.yaxis.set_ticks([0,100,200,300,400,500,1000])
# set what will actually be displayed at each tick.
ax.yaxis.set_ticklabels([0,100,200,300,400,500,'inf'])
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```
plt.plot(np.arange(5), np.arange(5))
plt.yticks(np.arange(5), [200, 400, 600, 800, 'inf'])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: The issue is that I have a lot of points, I do not want to display ticks for all. I just want to use default display + the last one (as inf).